# c# string replace not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, replace

I have this code

```
private string Site;

        public string SiteID
        {
            get {
                if (this.Type == 0)
                {
                    Site.Replace("&AElig;", "Æ");
                    Site.Replace("&Oslash;", "Ø");
                    Site.Replace("&Aring;", "Å");
                    Site.Replace("&aelig;", "æ");
                    Site.Replace("&oslash;", "ø");
                    Site.Replace("&aring;", "å");
                }

                return Site;
            }
            set { Site = value; }
        }
```

In my model class. But when it comes to getting a string that looks like this:
`"L&Oslash;NX"` and I step through it in debugging mode and its exactly the same after.
Even though this line:

```
Site.Replace("&Oslash;", "Ø");
```

should have changed it. Why doesn't it??

Comment: FYI if you are unaware there is `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`

Comment: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.keywords)

Answer (score 7):

The replace returns the modified string.  It does not change the existing one

```
Site = Site.Replace("&AElig;", "Æ");
```

Comment: ah thank you! Googled alot even and didnt find that :S